# Divide Time Period across different Time Frames (Calculating Interest)

Tags: excel

In the attached excel file

http://www.sendspace.com/file/y9qj0t

I've got a time period "C3:D3" (time periods can be altered by user) and a sum of money for which i need to calculate interest across different time periods with different interest rates.
You can check out my formula in "E6:E" but somehow I'm not postive it's correct.
I want the formula to divide days of the above period of time across the different int. rates time frames & return "0" when int.rates times frames are before or after my time period.

Also, I'm not certain how to handle the last int. rate time frame (ie the last time int. rate was changed so it's not a closed time frame B50:C50). B50 is occupied by the last date int. rate was changed and C50 equals above mentioned D3. Does it make any sense?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to answer your previous question....but you deleted it...

Your method works, I think, but this formula can give you the correct result in a single cell without using columns E and F

`=SUMPRODUCT(LOOKUP(ROW(INDIRECT(C3&":"&D3-1)),B6:D50))/365*E3`

it doesn't matter what value you put in C50

The `ROW/INDIRECT` part gives you an "array" of all dates from C3 to D3-1 and that array is the lookup value for `LOOKUP` function, looking up each date in B6:B50 and returning the corresponding rate from D6:D50. SUMPRODUCT then sums all those rates. Diving by 365 then gives you the average annual rate. I get 2.89 for your example, the same as your result

Comment: Ok, I get it. I was going to ask about the formula but you clarified it! Thank you so much... BTW I get it that your formula is by far more solid and compact and combines different ranges but was my formula viable? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited my answer too because I hadn't realised what your were doing first time - I think your method works too - I tried with different date ranges and both methods get the same results